# Material ui snackbar/popup not rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, material-ui

Here is my code to show up the snackbar once the seterror is detected - i cant get to figure out why it doesn't work in one of the methods - however it does show up in the return statement of my component which isn't exactly what I need. I need to return the snack bar only if the seterror is detected. I tried using material input `inputComponent` prop to call my `<ErrorMsg>` doesn't accept the component either. Help please!!

```js
const _onBlur = () => {
  updateData(value);
  _isValid(value);
};

const _isValid = (value: string) => {
  if (isNaN(+value) != false) {
    seterror(true);
    return (
      /* eslint-disable */
      <ErrorMsg message={message} />
    );
  } else {
    seterror(false);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        id={id}
        value={value}
        onChange={_onChange}
        onBlur={_onBlur}
        error={error}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I made an edit that makes the code readable and noticed that there was a superfluous 
`};` in the code. Was that a typo or was that the error?

Comment: i believe a typo, because this component doesnt render the pop up neither has any error on console